# Is unroot still possible in this case?

Tags: unrooting, lg-optimus-one

I have an LG Optimus One ( LGP500 ) running 2.2 and I rooted it using the z4root tool, version 1.0. From what I saw, back then it didn't have an unroot option. In the meantime, I did an update using the LG Mobile Tool, and I think it updated my system to 2.2.2 .

I noticed that the newer versions of z4root have an unroot option, so I upgraded my z4root from 1.0 to 1.3, to try to unroot the phone ... but I only see the `Temporary root` and `Permanent root` options. I tried pressing the `Permanent root` and it seemed to do something, after which it returned me to my `Home`. From this, I'm drawing the conclusion that rerooting did not work. I am assuming z4root needs to root, so that the unroot option is available.

Is there anyway I could unroot my phone now?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're trying to accomplish here. Running the update with LG's tool more than likely unrooted the phone in the process (most carrier/manufacturer updates will do this). Running z4root would then attempt to reroot it, but now you want to unroot again? Also, if rerooting didn't work, then I'd assume you're already unrooted.

Comment: I agree with eldarerathis.

Comment: You know what? I think you may be right. I tried to do a `su` in the terminal emulator and I couldn't. It gave me a `su:permission denied`. So, everytime I will update, the same process will apply? Unroot is guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, OTA (or in this case, manual) update will most likely always remove root.

Comment: And how can I remove traces of the phone being rooted? In case I will ever need to bring it in for warranty reasons? Also, guys, please post answers so I can mark them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have come to realize, official updates (OTA or manual) will most likely patch previous exploits to obtain root and you will most likely lose root during the process of updating.  It is recommend to NOT allow updates if you wish to keep root.  Certain mods, such as CyanogenMod, will automatically block OTA updates to keep this from being a problem.