# How can I remove traces of my phone ever being rooted?

Tags: unrooting

I rooted my phone and then an update unrooted it. I described my story [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/is-unroot-still-possible-in-this-case) . I am glad that the update unrooted it, I was also planning on doing it myself.

What can I do to make sure that all traces of me having root access on the phone are erased? I'd like to do this, so that if I have to go in for warranty purposes, I don't have any problems.

I'm guessing uninstalling z4root would be the first step. What else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, doing a factory restore on the device should eliminate anything left over the device.

Usually the process goes:

1. Revert back to  your earliest NANDROID backup (that you should have taken right after you rooted).  If you don't have it, then flash a stock ROM.
2. Run the unroot reversal process (in this case you ran an official update)
3. Remove any left over root applications (SuperUser app, etc.).
4. If necessary, wipe the device by restoring to factory settings.

If I'm missing anything, leave a comment and I'll update this.